# submodules git visual studio "fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output" can they just checkin?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-submodules

Any reason why git submodules in Visual Studio 2017 just don't want to checkin?  I keep getting

> fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output

Seems like sometimes they **DO** checkin, but most of the time they don't.  Am I misunderstanding something?

[image]

Comment: I recommend using the standard git terminology. Eg use commit not checkin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my case the problem was that not all the files had been saved when trying to commit.

[This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102348/when-commit-i-get-fatal-unexpected-sequence-in-com.html) showed me where to look.

> "I got this exception when the file with changes I was attempting to commit was not saved"

Answer (score 8):

With assistance from the main answer. The submodule change was the only change that required committing, and attempting to commit produced the error.

Making an additional minor change in a any project file, such as removing an empty line, following by a 'Commit All' on the 2 changes, solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and the reason was that submodule was opened in VS code and I made some changes in VS code editor which was uncommitted. committing those changes in VS code solved my problem.

In my case, submodule was an Angular 8 project that I was integrating in a solution with many existing projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact error because the sub-module was in the repo but no longer referenced in the solution but it did reference a project that was still in the solution.

Here's what I did.

I could not find the submodule referenced in the changes list.

I used Git Bash to attempt to remove the offending submodule using this https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255#gistcomment-2116278

The response : `rm: cannot remove 'EventStream.Management': Is a directory`

Realised that I have an old project that is removed from the solution (so I was not seeing it), but *not* removed from the repo because it still existed in the solution folder. That de-referenced project did reference a project that is still in the solution that has since been updated. I believe this was causing the unexpected sequence error.

I removed the folder containing the de-referenced project and I rebuilt the repo (I wanted to start a new master anyway). Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was a bad commit I did before the current commit which affected the current one. I reverted the old one, fixed some file changes issues and then the commit succeeded