# Git Hub - Fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio, github

I've spent the better part of today and last night on this and I can't figure it out.

I've searched for a similar error but none of the descriptions seem to fit my case.

My issue is that in visual studio, it's showing that I have uncommitted changes. In this case, it's the deletion of a file.

context: I'm doing a code-along tutorial for Reactjs and I delete my src file and replace it with the tutorial's in case I miss anything and commit along the way. It's been working flawlessly more than half of the way done with the tutorial.

Anyway, now when I try to commit to Github through Visual Studio, I get this error showing, [image]

I've tried revert and reset --hard to before when I got this error and no luck. I don't know what else to do.

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50052743/1030675

Answer (score 0):

I somehow got lucky and figured it out.

I just had to delete the existing Aux.js file and it was able to work.